# Reference request: Edmond's Algorithm for integer hull

Tags: reference-request, convex-optimization, integer-programming

I'm looking for a good reference for the algorithm (supposedly by Edmonds) to compute the integer hull of a polytope, not by cutting plane methods but by starting with a set of integer points and then optimizing into the direction of the facet given by the points until another integer point is reached.

The reference I found just leads to a small remark in an Edmonds paper. Moreover I couldn't find any description of the algorithm in some standard text books.

Thank you!

Richard